# How do I retrieve fetch PromiseValue in async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to get the result of a fetch in an asynchronous way like this:

```
var result = await fetch(`/api/collection/get-collection.php?name=${this._name}`, {method: `GET`});
console.log(result.json());
```

but when I look at the console I get this:

```
Promise {<pending>}
  __proto__: Promise
  [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
  [[PromiseValue]]: Object
    content: (176) [...]
    extra: {...}
    message: ...
    __proto__: Object
```

So I feel like when it comes to the console.log the promise is still pending? (there's a tooltip saying "Value below was evaluated just now" so I guess it's updated when the promise is resolved? And of course the code below (not shown here) doesn't work cause it needs the value of fetch's return. And I don't even know how to access PromiseValue.

What is the proper way to make an asynchronous fetch call?

PS: I'm using vanilla JS.

Comment: `result.json()` returns another `Promise` that you'll need to `await`.

Comment: And please: NEVER let an Promise be uncatched (bad practise).

Comment: Oh. Okay yeah that's it, can you write an answer so I can validate it?

On a side note if you have an advise on how to write a proper asynchronous call (I mean the good practice if there is one).

Comment: @Kai Lehmann okay I'm really new to this (promises and async and so on), if you have a code example of how to write a good asynchonous call that'd be nice. I'm trying to read on the subject but most of it goes over my head.

Comment: @Gaetan L. Check this 


const fetchPromise = fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people");
fetchPromise.then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(people => {
  console.log(people);
});

Comment: yourPromise.then(data => { //make fancy things}).catch(error => {console.error(error);}).finally(()=>{ //things that will happen after regardless of success or failure});

Comment: @Gaetan L. 

Kai has explained it well .
Check this link too . This might help https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Why would you mix `async`/`await` with `.then`? I'd go full `async`/`await` if I have access to them. There's no obvious good practices that I'm aware of in this area, just remember that this code still is async (while looking sync), see https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/, and feel free to close your question :)

Comment: Honestly up until this point I thought async/await was bad and Promises were the new way to go. I thought asynchronous was like old practices and I'm struggling since the beginning of my project to make everything work with .then :D

Comment: Put simply, async/await is just syntax sugar to make promise-based code looks synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the fetch call using async-await like this.

```
try {

   const response = await fetch(`/api/collection/get-collection.php?name=${this._name}`, {method: `GET`});

   const result = await response.json()

   // do something with the data
   console.log(data);

} catch(error) {

  // your error handling code

  console.log(error)

}
```

if you do not want to use async-await then you can use `.then` to resolve the promise.

```
 fetch(`/api/collection/get-collection.php?name=${this._name}`, {method: `GET`})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
           // do something with the data
           console.log(data)
         })
        .catch(error => {
            // your error handling code
            console.log(error)
         });
```